# Passing a variable in a URL while submitting data with AJAX in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to submit data with AJAX in Laravel but i keep getting the following error 
http://localhost:8000/comments/19 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

The post_id is the variable which declared in the route:-
[image]

and here is the code in the page:-

```
@extends('main')

@section('title', "| $post->title")

@section('content')

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <img src=" {{ asset('images/' . $post->image) }} " height="400" width="600" />
            <h1> {{ $post->title }}</h1>
            <p>{!! $post->body !!}</p>
            <hr>
            <p>Posted In: {{ $post->category->name }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <h3 class="comments-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>  {{ $post->comments()->count() }} Comments</h3>
            @foreach($post->comments as $comment)
                <div class="comment">
                    <div class="author-info">

                        <img src="{{ "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5(strtolower(trim($comment->email))) . "?s=50&d=monsterid" }}" class="author-image">
                        <div class="author-name">
                            <h4>{{ $comment->name }}</h4>
                            <p class="author-time">{{ date('F nS, Y - g:iA' ,strtotime($comment->created_at)) }}</p>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="comment-content" id="comment">
                        {{ $comment->comment }}
                    </div>

                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div id="comment-form" class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" style="margin-top: 50px;">
            {{ Form::open() }}

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {{ Form::label('name', "Name:") }}
                        {{ Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {{ Form::label('email', 'Email:') }}
                        {{ Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        {{ Form::label('comment', "Comment:") }}
                        {{ Form::textarea('comment', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => '5']) }}

                        {{ Form::submit('Add Comment', ['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-block', 'style' => 'margin-top:15px;', 'id'=>'load']) }}
                    </div>
                </div>

            {{ Form::close() }}
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection

@section('scripts')

    {!! Html::script('js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js') !!}


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#load').click(function(event){
          event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: '{{route('comments.store', ['id' => 19])}} ',
                dataType: "html",
                success:function(data){
                    $("#comment").html(data);
                }
          })
      })
    })
    </script>
@endsection
```

Comment: check your error logs

Comment: everything works fine without AJAX but when its added, it gives that error

Comment: so find out what error is in error logs or by turning on error display and reading error in response body

Comment: i have seen it but i dont seem to understand it MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
shall i put the whole code in github and u take a look?

Comment: does it work using `GET`? You aren't sending any data so not sure why you used post in first place

Comment: thats what i get http://localhost:8000/comments/19 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
and yeah im trying to add a comment to the database

Comment: is page also on same port 8000?

Comment: yep , the whole server is on the same port just different routes, pretty basic stuff, running >> php artisan serve

Comment: and you tried changing request to a GET? error doesn't make sense if you tried with get

Comment: yea i tried with GET , it said Method Not Allowed

Comment: inspect actual request in browser dev tools network and make sure url is correct. Need more detail from error log also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how i solved it but i can't display it without refreshing nor styling it the same:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // post_id = $("h1:first").text();
    // console.log(post_id);
   // var myid = parseInt($('h1:last').text());


    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#load').click(function(event){
          event.preventDefault();



          var token = $('input[name=_token]').val();
          var name = $('input[name=name]').val();
          var email = $('#email').val();

          var comment = $('#bant').val();

            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                dataType: "html",
                url: '{{route('comments.store', ['id' =>  $post->id ])}} ',
                data: {_token: token, name: name, email: email, comment:comment} 

                    });
                }
          )
      })

    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I saw your request on twitter so I thought I would try to help.

The Most common reason that I have seen this type of error in Laravel when using AJAX is that CSRF tokens don't get sent with AJAX requests. Just for testing purposes I would suggest removing your comments.store route from the CSRF middleware. This is obviously not safe for production to keep it this way. But if you remove CSRF validation and it works then it makes it easy for us to know that that is the problem.

If the CSRF is the problem then we know that the token isn't being sent with the Ajax request. On Laravels documentation it does explain how to accomplish this. We need to add the CSRF token to the headers of every Ajax request. Information on how to do that is available here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

There is discussion above about the HTTP method that you should be using. POST is the correct HTTP method to use according to your routes list shown in the question. So keep it on POST.

Also double check what version of Laravel you are using. In Laravel 5.3 and beyond you usually don't need to manually load jQuery as it is by default loaded as part of your app.js file if you're using the built in asset pipeline.

Lastly if you continue to have problems please diagnose it using the "inspect element" in the browser. You should be able to read any JS errors in the console and be able to dig into the actual HTTP request attempt to further diagnose it. Let us know if you are seeing any errors in that console.

Let me know if that doesn't help and I can edit my answer to help you out. On an related note I'm going to be re-building that tutorial series updated to Laravel 5.4 in the coming month or so. That tutorial series was done on an early version of 5.2 and a lot has changed now that 5.3 has come and gone and 5.4 is out now.

Comment: yeah i've watched all the series and it was amazing, i followed you on laravel 5.3 and it works like a charm , just slight changes. your code is awesome.i'm waiting for your next series. thank you for being the best!